# Why does click method is not working in Selenium in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

`click()` method is not working in selenium python. I have used all of the methods which are available in selenium documentation. I want to apply automation to this URL.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ser = Service("D:\chromedriver")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://cultivatedculture.com/mailscoop/')

driver.maximize_window()
sleep(2)
# log = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "LOG IN")
# sleep(2)
# log.click()


for i in range(3):
    #-----------------------------------------------------
    name = 'jay kakadiya'
    domain = 'gmail.com'

    inp = driver.find_element(By.ID ,'name')
    inp.send_keys(name)

    inp2 = driver.find_element(By.ID ,'domain')
    inp2.send_keys(domain)
    sleep(1)
    btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="find_btn"]')
    sleep(1)

    btn.click()
    actionChains.move_to_element(btn).click().perform()
    print("press click")
    #-----------------------------------------------------------

    # if i == 0:
    #
    #     popup1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="jsSignupModalForm"]/div[2]/div/p[5]/span'))
    #     sleep(1)
    #     actionChains.move_to_element(popup1).click().perform()
    #     popup2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="jsLoginModalForm"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]'))
    #     sleep(1)
    #     actionChains.move_to_element(popup2).click().perform()
    #     driver.find_element_by_id('jsUserLoginModal').send_keys('pagiri2277@flowminer.com')
    #     driver.find_element_by_id('jsUserLoginModal').send_keys('jaykakadiya63522')
    #     sleep(1)
    #     popup3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jsLoginModalForm"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div"]')
    #     actionChains.move_to_element(popup3).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fillup the *`Full Name`* and *`Company Website`* fields next to click on the element <kbd>Find It</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get('https://cultivatedculture.com/mailscoop/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#name[name='name']"))).send_keys("jay kakadiya")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#domain[name='domain']").send_keys("gmail.com")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#find_btn > span > span"))))
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: cultivatedculture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below css selector:

```
button#find_btn span
```

it is unique in HTMLDOM.

You can click it with using explicit wait like below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#find_btn span"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Not sure why would you need a loop for this though.